# UITextChecker: Way to Check If Word is Already Correct?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios8, uilexicon, uitextchecker

UITextChecker' `rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:range:startingAt:wrap:language:` returns nil if no correction is found. However I was wondering if there's a way to tell if no correction was found because A. It's already correct or B. Nothing Exists for the current word.

This is what I have right now:

```
if (!arrayOfPossibleCorrections || !arrayOfPossibleCorrections.count) {
    //If nothing found bc it's already correct leave it alone
    //Else dosomething
} else {
    //Replace currentWord with correctWord
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple developer library, [`rangeOfMisspelledWordInString`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextChecker/rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:range:startingAt:wrap:language:) returns  `{NSNotFound, 0}` if no **misspelled** word is found which is exactly what you are asking for.

It is [`guessesForWordRange`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextChecker/guessesForWordRange:inString:language:) that will return an empty array if no correction is found.

In short you should call `guessesForWordRange` only when there is a misspelled word range returned by `rangeOfMisspelledWordInString`.

Comment: but this includes also some words and abbreviations that are not so common. and almost unusable for most of the users. is there any way to neglect these words and abbreviations?